# Using the same 'OnClickListener' in different Activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I was **defining and using a custom OnClickListener** (i.e. `MyOnClickListener`) inside the file of the Fragment I was using at the moment.

Keeping writing code I realized that **I needed the same listener also in another Fragment** that happened to be in **another Activity** as well.

I created therefore the file `MyOnClickListener.java` copying all the code I was using in the first Fragment for it earlier, but now I get the following errors:

> Cannot resolve method 'getActivity()'
>
> Cannot resolve method 'getResources()'

Note: I read on *stackoverflow* that one solution may be just writing `MainActivity.this` in place of `getActivity()`, but in my situation I need to use the same in **two different activities**. What should I do?

**EDIT: Here's the code of `MyOnClickListener`**
It just has to display a matrix of icons:

```
class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    
    private LabeledButton labeledButton;

    MyOnClickListener(LabeledButton labeledButton) {
    super();
    this.labeledButton = labeledButton;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Button iconButton = (Button) view;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); // ERROR HERE
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater(); // ERROR HERE
    final View viewLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_matrix_icons, null);
    builder.setView(viewLayout);
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    // Set-up listeners of icon button
    Button imageButtons[][] = new Button[3][3];
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            Resources res = getResources(); // ERROR HERE
            TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.listIcon);
            int idDrawable = icons.getResourceId(i + 3 * j, 1); // ERROR HERE
            icons.recycle();
            LinearLayout grid = (LinearLayout) viewLayout;
            LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) grid.getChildAt(i);
            imageButtons[i][j] = (Button) row.getChildAt(j); // Retrieve the right image in the grid
            imageButtons[i][j].setBackgroundResource(idDrawable);
            String nameIcon = getResources().getResourceEntryName(idDrawable); // ERROR HERE
            ImageOnClickListener imageOnClickListener = new ImageOnClickListener(iconButton, alertDialog, idDrawable, nameIcon, labeledButton);
            imageButtons[i][j].setOnClickListener(imageOnClickListener);
        }
    }
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

Comment: show your code please

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this with your constructor

```
MyOnClickListener(LabeledButton labeledButton,Context context) {
   super();
   this.labeledButton = labeledButton;
   this.context = context;
}
```

Make sure you create context variable inside your MyOnClickListenerClass if not you will find error at the constructor line.Then you can replace all the `getActivity()` to `context`.

When you initiallize your `MyOnClickListener` make sure to pass the context parameter

For your inflater use this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly everywhere but here: `LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See update code. Because your fragment normally already have it own inflater by using context.getLayourInflater so you don't need to initilliaze your inflater but currently you using seperate class you need to initilliaze inflater to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

> I read on stackoverflow that one solution may be just writing
>   MainActivity.this in place of  getActivity(), but in my situation I
>   need to use the same in two different activities. What should I do?

If you put the OnClickListener in its own compilation unity, you can't use whawt *you read on Stackoverflow*. `MainActivity.this`, refers to a concrete and current instance of `MainActivity` (please, look it up what the keyword `this` means in java). If you need a Context, you can the parameter you get in the `onClick` callaback, `View view`, to retrieve it. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext())